# How to receive raw data from OTG USB connected to an Android device

Tags: android, usb

I need to receive raw data from a receiver (maybe in the form of binary in particular interval, maybe after every 5 seconds) that is connected to the Android device through an OTG cable.

I need to know whether this can be done with the help of Android core classes or any external API/SDK

Note:

1. I have a pair of transmitter and receiver.
2. Batteries inserted into the transmitter and it will automatically transmit the data to the receiver every 5 seconds.
3. I have installed OTG UART Hyperterminal free from the Google Play Store and when I open the port and get the main screen, I noticed that I received the hex data every 5 seconds. So the transmitter and receiver are working properly.

Here is a portion of my code :

- **Manifest File:**

  ```
  <activity android:name="com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples.DeviceListActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
  </activity>
  ```
- **Under /res/xml**
- **device_filter**

I received these details from code.

```
<usb-device
    vendor-id="1105"
    product-id="5798"
    class="2"
    subclass="0"
    protocol="0"
/>
```

**Source code:**

```
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbRequest;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Read_USB_Host_Receiver extends Activity {
  Button btnDeviceList;
  TextView txtResult;
  int iBulk=0;
  UsbManager usbManager;
  UsbDeviceConnection conn;
  BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver;
  PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
  UsbDevice dev;

  private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";

  public void run(UsbDevice sDevice) {
    UsbDevice dev = sDevice;
    txtResult.setText("1");
    if (dev == null)
      return;
    txtResult.setText("2");
    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
    txtResult.setText("3");
    if(usbManager.hasPermission(dev)) {
      Log.d("USB", " Permission OK");
    } else {
      txtResult.setText("4");
      Log.d("USB", " Permission faild");
      usbManager.requestPermission(dev, mPermissionIntent);
      if(usbManager.hasPermission(dev)) {
        txtResult.setText("5");
        Log.d("USB", "Now is Permission OK");
      }
    }
    conn = usbManager.openDevice(dev);
    Log.i("Interface Count: "+conn,""+dev.getInterfaceCount());
    Log.i("Using ",""+ String.format("%04X:%04X", sDevice.getVendorId(),sDevice.getProductId()));
    txtResult.setText("6");
    new AsynReadUCBHostEndPoint().execute();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read__usb__host__receiver);
    txtResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
    Log.i("deviceList size: ", ""+deviceList.size());
    Toast.makeText(Read_USB_Host_Receiver.this, ""+deviceList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
    while(deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
      UsbDevice dd = deviceIterator.next();
      dev = dd;
      if(usbManager.hasPermission(dev)) {
        Log.d("USB", " Permission OK");
      } else {
        Log.d("USB", " Permission faild");
        usbManager.requestPermission(dev, mPermissionIntent);
        if(usbManager.hasPermission(dev)) {
          Log.d("USB", "Now is Permission OK");
        }
      }
    }
    btnDeviceList = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDeviceList);
    btnDeviceList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        Log.i("deviceList size: ", ""+deviceList.size());
        Toast.makeText(Read_USB_Host_Receiver.this, ""+deviceList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        while(deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
          UsbDevice dd = deviceIterator.next();
          dev = dd;
          if (dd.getVendorId()==1105) {
            run(dd);
          }
        }
      }
    });

    mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
          synchronized (this) {
            UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.i("HELLO", "BYE");
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
              if(device != null) {
                //call method to set up device communication
                Log.i("HELLO1", "BYE1");
              }
            } else {
              //  Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device " + device);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_read__usb__host__receiver, menu);
    return true;
  }

  public void readUSBHostData() { }

  class AsynReadUCBHostEndPoint extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    String response, result;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      txtResult.setText("7");
      super.onPreExecute();
      dialog=new ProgressDialog(Read_USB_Host_Receiver.this);
      dialog.setMessage("Reading endpoint...");
      dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
      dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try {
        for (int j=0; j < dev.getInterfaceCount(); j++) {
          UsbInterface intf = dev.getInterface(j);
          UsbEndpoint endpoint = null;
          for (int i = 0; i < intf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
            if (intf.getEndpoint(i).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
              endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(i);
              break;
            }
          }
          if(endpoint != null) {
            if(usbManager.hasPermission(dev)) {
              Log.d("USB", " Permission OK");
            } else {
              Log.d("USB", " Permission faild");
              usbManager.requestPermission(dev, mPermissionIntent);
              if(usbManager.hasPermission(dev)) {
                Log.d("USB", "Now is Permission OK");
              }
            }
            conn = usbManager.openDevice(dev);
            conn.releaseInterface(intf);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
            if (conn!=null && conn.claimInterface(intf, true)) {
              int retVal = conn.bulkTransfer(endpoint, buffer, 64, 5000);
              Log.i("return of bluk:", "" + retVal);
              while(retVal == 0) {
                retVal = conn.bulkTransfer(endpoint, buffer, 64, 200);
                Log.i("return of bluk in while loop:", "" + retVal);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
      }
      return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      dialog.dismiss();
      txtResult.setText(result);
    }
  }

  public void GetData(UsbDevice dev) {
    for (int j=0; j < dev.getInterfaceCount(); j++) {
      UsbInterface intf = dev.getInterface(j);
      UsbEndpoint endpoint = null;
      for (int i = 0; i < intf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
        if (intf.getEndpoint(i).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
          endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(i);
          break;
        }
      }
      if(endpoint != null) {
        conn = usbManager.openDevice(dev);
        UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest(); // create an URB
        if (conn!=null) {
          boolean initilzed = request.initialize(conn, endpoint);
          if (!initilzed) {
            Log.e("USB CONNECTION FAILED", "Request initialization failed for reading");
            return;
          }
          while (true) {
            int bufferMaxLength = endpoint.getMaxPacketSize();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferMaxLength);
            if (request.queue(buffer, bufferMaxLength) == true) {
              if (conn.requestWait() == request) {
                String result = new String(buffer.array());
                Log.i("GELEN DATA : ", result);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is this done ? how you achieved this?

Comment: It's been a long time since the topic, but did you try decompile the Hyperterminal mobile application you stated. If you can get raw data from the app, then you can try decompile it by a decompiler application like jadx gui and get source code. The source code can give some clues about how can you capture the data.